# 'Find' in all opened documents in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, search, find, find-in-files

As we all know that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is the way to find some required text within a file, but how do we go about to find a desired text in all open documents in Notepad++?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, and then click "*Find All in All Opened Documents*":

[image: notepad++ find window]

Alternatively, you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> (as the 'O' is underlined).

Comment: This answer is so straight forward, I start to wonder if some people even read what is on their screen. (not meant against you Attie, this is a valid answer)

Comment: It's not obvious enough since we're still up-voting this answer.  My initial thought was to look in "Find in Files" for this option since I think of each tab as a "file".

Comment: Just pointing out that, in newer versions (v8.4.6 at least), the placement of "Find All in All Opened Documents" and "Find All in Current Document" are swapped. I was so focused on the expected output that didn't check this for quite some time.